# Get text when enter is pressed in a text box in wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a (single line) TextCtrl. The user types data into this. When they press enter, the contents of the box need to be extracted so they can be processed. I can't figure out how to catch enter being pressed.

According to the docs, with the style wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER set on my TextCtrl, it should generate a wx.EVT_COMMAND_TEXT_ENTER event when enter is pressed in the box, which I could then catch. However, wx.EVT_COMMAND_TEXT_ENTER seems not to exist (I get "module has no attribute EVT_COMMAND_TEXT_ENTER), so I'm a bit stuck. Googling just gets a couple of hits of people complaining wx.EVT_COMMAND_TEXT_ENTER doesn't work, so I guess I need another way of doing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've never seen `wx.EVT_COMMAND_TEXT_ENTER`. I have used `wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER` though...

Comment: Ah, yes, this is the event that's generated. I guess this is a difference between wxPython and the C++ version, then. EVT_COMMAND_TEXT_ENTER is mentioned here: http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxtextctrl.html

Answer (score 7):

Use `style = wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER` in **TextCtrl** and Bind with `Event wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER`

```
self.Text_Enter = wx.TextCtrl(self , 2 ,style = wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER, size =(125,150), pos = (170,0))

self.Text_Enter.SetForegroundColour(wx.RED)

self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.Txt_Ent, id = 2)
def Txt_Ent(self,event):
   msg1 = (str(self.Text_Enter.GetValue()))
   wx.MessageBox(msg1)
```